# Alfresco Form field validation Javascript not being loaded by the browser

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm hoping someone here can help out with this problem, because I've done everything as per the book, to create a Javascript function for validating an Alfresco form field. Here's what I've done:

Altered the share-config-custom.xml file, as follows:

```
<forms>
  <dependencies>
    <js src="js/date-range-validator.js" />
  </dependencies>

  <form>
    <appearance>
      <field id="myfield:dfc-start-date">
        <constraint-handlers>
          <constraint type="MANDATORY" validation-handler="myspace.forms.validation.checkDateRangeValidity" event="keyup"/>
        </constraint-handlers>
      </field>
    ...
  </form>  
</forms>
```

Created a date-range-validator.js file, which I placed in `src/main/assembly/web/js`

```
if (typeof myspace == "undefined" || !myspace) {
  var myspace = {};
}

myspace.forms.validation.checkDateRangeValidity = function checkDateRangeValidity(field, args, event, form, silent, message) {
  var valid = true;
  alert('Checked date ' + field);
  return valid;
}
```

However, when the form is displayed I get an exception because "myspace" isn't defined, so it looks like my validator code isn't being loaded. I've tried placing the Javascript file in a variety of locations within the project, but I never see my Javascript validation code in the browser.

So I suppose it's a question of where to place the Javascript within the project structure.

Comment: which sdk version you are using?

Comment: Well it's Alfresco Share 5.2.d. (Community edition)

Comment: are you making changes directly in alfresco?

Comment: I'm not putting files directly to the running instance of Alfresco. All my source files are in the project build structure. I'm building the AMP and deploying it that way.

Comment: please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I got a solution thanks to Jeff Potts, who suggested that I put the form definition into an extension module.
Details on the Alfresco forum.

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/240434-form-field-validation-handler-issue

```
<extension>
  <modules>
    <module>
        <id>Someco Share Form Configuration</id>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
        <configurations>

            <config>
                <forms>
                    <dependencies>
                        <js src="/resources/someco-share/js/validator.js"/>
                    </dependencies>
                </forms>
            </config>



            <config evaluator="node-type" condition="sc:doc">
                <forms>
                    <form>
                        <field-visibility>
                            <show id="cm:name" />
                            <show id="cm:title" force="true" />
                            <show id="sc:someProp" />

                        </field-visibility>
                        <appearance>
                            <field id="cm:name">
                                <control>
                                    <control-param name="maxLength">255</control-param>
                                </control>
                            </field>
                            <field id="cm:title">
                                <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
                            </field>
                            <field id="sc:someProp" label-id="form.field.label.sc.someProp" description-id="form.field.description.sc.someProp" help-id="form.field.help.sc.someProp">
                                <constraint-handlers>
                                    <constraint type="scDateValidator" message-id="constraint.scDateValidation" validation-handler="SomeCo.forms.validation.scSomePropValidatior" event="onChange"/>
                                </constraint-handlers>
                            </field>
                        </appearance>
                    </form>

                </config>

            </configurations>
        </module>
    </modules>
  </extension>
```

Answer (score 2):

You javascript file should be at share/src/main/resources/META-INF/js location.

Follow This link for validation handler.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-share-form-field-validation-handlers.html

Comment: That is exactly the page I've been using.

Comment: please check now.

Comment: I placed my js file in the src/main/resources/META-INF/js directory, but the file is nowhere to be seen in the browser's js resources when I load the page

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing the enclosing `<config>` element that should be a parent of `<forms>`.

Comment: I do have that element Jeff. That piece of XML is just a small section of the share-config-custom.xml file. The whole file is well formed and syntactically correct.